# how to perfom crud operations for billing in graphQl APIs

Tags: e

{"errors":{"base":["It appears that this application is currently owned by a Shop.           It must be migrated to the Shopify partners area before it can create charges with the API."]}}

HTTP/1.1 201 Created

{

"application_charge": {

```
"id": 1017262349,

"name": "Super Duper Expensive action",

"api_client_id": 755357713,

"price": "100.00",

"status": "pending",

"return_url": "http://super-duper.shopifyapps.com/",

"test": true,

"created_at": "2024-01-02T09:01:11-05:00",

"updated_at": "2024-01-02T09:01:11-05:00",

"currency": "USD",

"charge_type": null,

"decorated_return_url": "http://super-duper.shopifyapps.com/?charge_id=1017262349",

"confirmation_url": "https://jsmith.myshopify.com/admin/charges/755357713/1017262349/ApplicationCharge/confirm_application_charge?signature=BAh7BzoHaWRpBA0xojw6EmF1dG9fYWN0aXZhdGVU--baad61b6ba1e9fbbbc4aea9da6f25c2b49058185"
```

}

}